# JS Regex problems

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a Number in between a set of straight brackets, example:

Match the `0` in `actionFields[actionFields][0][data[Report][action]]`

This is what I have so far and I keep getting null.

```
var match, matchRegEx = /^\(?\[(\d)\]\)$/;
nameAttr = "actionFields[actionFields][0][data[Report][action]]", 
match = matchRegEx.exec(nameAttr);
```

Comment: Your expression tries to match literal parenthesis (`\(`, `\)`) but there are none in your string. Why do you have them there? Also, your expression is anchored at the beginning and end, so only strings such as `([5])` or `[3])` would be matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your regular expression, you're matching the beginning of the string, zero or one `(`, then a `[`, then a `\d`, then a `]`, then a `)`, then the end of the string.

You should just be able to get away with `/\[(\d)\]/`, unless you're expecting the `[0]` construct to show up elsewhere in your string.

[Here's a RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%5C%5B%28%5Cd%29%5C%5D&input=actionFields%5BactionFields%5D%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5BReport%5D%5Baction%5D%5D) showing this.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thank you. Also thank you for that RegexPal, such a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be:

```
\[(\d+)\]
```

and capture the first group.

One problem with your regex is that it is anchored at the beginning of input (`^`) *and* at the end `$`.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one number `/\d+/`
You can test only for the number